# REST and HTTP API Client for java like RestSharp(http://restsharp.org/)

Tags: java, android, json, http, rest

I have used [restsharp](http://restsharp.org/) for some of my .net projects. and I found it pretty useful for getting Json Data from web-service and converting them to .net objects. I need a similar framework for java. I want to use it for reading the same Json web-service  for my android apps.

Comment: did you Googled this ? cause there are many frameworks for this purpose

Comment: yes, i googled this. but could not find one like restSharp.

Comment: may be you need to improve your google skills, because every restful framework out there does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can try reasteasy cleint http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/.

Comment: Is it a rest client API ? I need a REST client API where i will give the webservice URL that return data in Json format. the rest client api should read the json data and able to convert that json data to my custome object.

Comment: Yes ReastEasy has a client api too. check this http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html